# Is it possible to dynamically register menus?

Tags: menus, metabox

I have a template, lets call it `menu.php`, which contains a menu.
I would like the user to set the menu on this page by using WordPress's own menus, so I don't have to create something custom for it.

They can in theory have multiple `menu.php` pages.

The page template has a custom meta box which saves a menu slug to the database.
When the page loads, I was hoping to be able to load this slug and set the current menu by using this slug.

The problem is that since I set the slug dynamically, I don't know how to register the menu.

I thought maybe I could register the menu when I saved the the slug to the database, but that didn't quite work out.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Register a menu is really register a menu location, but I think you don't need to register locations so you can avoid the register step. I think what you need is [`wp_nav_menu( )`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) function. For example, in the page template:

```
//Get the menu slug stored in page custom meta field
//Replace menu_meta_field_name with the correct name of the meta field
$menu_slug = get_post_meta( get_queried_object_id(), 'menu_meta_field_name', true);
wp_nav_menu( array( 'menu' => $menu_slug ) );
```

Comment: This works like a charm, thanks! And it is so much better than how I tried to solve it.